# Want Manipulate to be low resolution enough to render fast but no so low resolution that it is useless

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, manipulate

When using Manipulate to graph a simple surface (sum of 2 sine waves) with Plot3D, setting PerformanceGoal->"Quality" makes it take about 1/3 second to render, while "Speed" sets it at such a low resolution that you can't even see the general shape of the plot.

Is there a way to set the render quality to something in-between or to adjust how much rendering it does when set to "Speed"?

```
k = 1;
range = 20;
Manipulate[{Show[
   Plot3D[
    Sin[k*(Sqrt[(x - p1[[1]])^2 + (y - p1[[2]])^2] - t)],
    {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range}, 
    BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"
   ]
  ]}, 
 {t, 0, 5}, 
 {p1, {-range, -range}, {range, range}}
]
```

Comment: If you refrain from setting any PerformanceGoal, Manipulate should automatically adjust this parameter to have two different values, a speedy, low quality setting for when you are changing a parameter or rotating a plot, and a slower, higher quality setting used to "clean up" the plot when you let go of the controls. This works well e.g. in this: `Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Sin[3 x + 4 y] + Sin[4 x^2 - y^2], {x, y} \[Element] 
   Rectangle[{0, 0}, {t, t}]],
 {{t, 1}, 0.1, 3}
 ]`, but right now you have us guessing at your problem. **You should share your code so we can provide more specific help.**

Comment: I already tried that. The problem is that the speedy low quality is so low that the whole surface is just a vague blur until I release the mouse.

Comment: code:    k = 1;
range = 20;
Manipulate[{Show[
   Plot3D[Sin[
     k*(Sqrt[(x - p1[[1]])^2 + (y - p1[[2]])^2] - t)], {x, -range, 
     range}, {y, -range, range}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]]}, {t, 0, 
  5}, {p1, {-range, -range}, {range, range}}]

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way to adjust the quality of the speedy setting to make it slightly higher quality

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. Unfortunately I don't know how to accomplish what you want off the top of my head, but I'll look into this tomorrow. Thanks for providing a code sample.

Comment: If your question gets reopened, I will post an answer, but basically you can get something like the performance compromise you want by increasing `PlotPoints` above the default. It will be system dependent, but I get reasonable results on my system by setting `PlotPoints -> 50`.

Comment: What @m_goldberg said.Set `PlotPoints->50` and add the option `Mesh->None`. The result is quite speedy. One of you two should post a (self)answer now. PS Neither `Show` nor the curly braces around it are necessary. Just leave `Plot3D` as the first argument to `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ControlActive` to fine-tune the behaviour of `PlotPoints` and `PerformanceGoal` while the variables are being manipulated.

```
With[{k = 1, range = 20}, 
 Manipulate[
  Plot3D[Sin[
    k*(Sqrt[(x - p1[[1]])^2 + (y - p1[[2]])^2] - t)], {x, -range, 
    range}, {y, -range, range}, Mesh -> 10, 
   PlotPoints -> ControlActive[30, 60], 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .2}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PerformanceGoal -> ControlActive["Speed", "Quality"]], 
  {t, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {p1, 
  {-range, -range}, {range, range}, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]]
```

Now while the controls are active (being manipulated) `Plot3D` will plot with `PlotPoints->30` and `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"`.  However, once the controls are released `Plot3D` will do a finishing plot with `PlotPoints->60` and `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"`.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can get something like the performance compromise you ask for by increasing `PlotPoints` above the default. Graphics performance is system dependent, but I get reasonable results on my system by setting `PlotPoints -> 50`. You may need a different setting. Lowering the number of mesh points also helps. I used `Mesh -> 10,`.

Here is the modified version of your code that I found both responsive and pleasing to the eye.

```
With[{k = 1, range = 20},
  Manipulate[
    Plot3D[Sin[k*(Sqrt[(x - p1[[1]])^2 + (y - p1[[2]])^2] - t)], 
      {x, -range, range}, {y, -range, range},
      PlotPoints -> 50,
      Mesh -> 10,
      BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .2},
      ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"],
    {t, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {p1, {-range, -range}, {range, range}, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

[image: plot]